# One topic per paragraph when discussing advantages and disadvantages

Tags: paragraphs, tech-writing

I'm in the process of discussing advantages and disadvantages in a science paper I'm writing. I'm not sure if it's best to include them in two separate body paragraphs, one for advantages and one for disadvantages with their own topic sentences.

Or would it be better to create body paragraphs for each singular advantage/disadvantage?

Comment: It depends on how long the arguments would be. A paragraph should generally be no longer than 1/3 of a page. It can be much shorter if it's part of a list (with list markers). If you're using running text, the most important markers for your arguments would be like 'first...further/second...' etc.

Comment: I'm not sure this is about English language and usage. Whatever advice one might give here for organizing arguments for and against a proposition would apply to writing in any language. Is there an SE forum on writing technique?

Comment: Hello, Josh. I don't know who manages to get some of these tags included; writing advice (including discourse grammar) is off-topic here.  Ball-park advice is three to twenty lines per paragraph; you can ask someone who's done it before what is considered best practice as regards sub-topics. But isn't there an in-house style guide recommending a particular style of formatting?